# Cocoa/Obj-C - Dateformat change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, date

I got an application wich read XML file and extract data of the nodes and put the data into textfields.

One of the node is `<date>20110305162831</date>`

In my textfield I got: `20110305162831`

Whish is not very understandable for enduser...

How can i format it like:

`2011/03/05 16:28:31`

Is it possible?

Here is my AppControler.m code:

```
    NSMutableArray* dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    NSXMLElement* root  = [doc rootElement];
    NSXMLElement* root  = [doc rootElement];

    NSArray* dateArray = [root nodesForXPath:@"//Report/ReportCreationDate" error:nil];
    for(NSXMLElement* xmlElement in dateArray)
        [dates addObject:[xmlElement stringValue]];

    NSString * date = [dates objectAtIndex:0];

    [dateTextField setStringValue:date];

    [doc release];
    [dates release];
```

If someone can help me, it would be great!

Thanks in advance

Miskia

Comment: Have you looked at NSDateFormatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];    
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"20110305163031"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString* date_str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date];
```

Comment: How can I set it up in my code shown above? Thanks for your answer Max :)

Comment: It's working, but for my example, I got this result: 06.04.639240 whish is incorrect

Comment: dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: gets time in seconds, so check that value and convert it to seconds.

Comment: You need to create two formatters. One to create a date from the xml data and one to format the date for the dateTextField.

Comment: Just realized that 20110305162831 is 2011/03/05 16:28:31 and not milliseconds =)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I begin to understand. Is it possible that you edit your code to fit with mine? It would be nice. Cause I can't do it :( But the date is a variable (depends of the xml opened) so why the 20110305163031 appears in the code?

Comment: It's ok. Thansk a lot for your help Max! Have a nice day!